# error with using object.keys and foreach to display data using document get element by id

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm trying to get my js script to display the data in the object `udata`.

I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null.

I have tested using a string (`var str = 'test'`), and that gives no error, but as soon as I switch to using `itemValue` as the id to check, I get errors. I have tried using `.toString()` to make the key a string, but that doesn't work either.
 Not sure what to do. The `!= null` statement should make the `foreach` avoid the null operations in the few cases the object key is not intended to correspond to an id in the html.

I would appreciate any help!

```
if(localStorage.udata != null){
    var udata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('udata'));

    Object.keys(udata).forEach(function (itemValue) {
        if(document.getElementById(itemValue).innerHTML != null)
            document.getElementById(itemValue).innerHTML = udata[itemValue];
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your check is actually causing the error. You have to check if

```
 document.getElementById(itemValue)
```

is `null`, trying to access `.innerHTML` is what results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

> The != null statement should make the foreach avoid the null
>   operations in the few cases the object key is not intended to
>   correspond to an id in the html.

This is incorrect. If an element with ID `itemValue` does not exist, then `document.getElementById(itemValue)` will be `null`, so trying to use `.innerHTML` on that `null` value is what is causing the error. You need to check `document.getElementById(itemValue) != null` instead.